# sql group by dob in decades

Tags: sql

Hi my question is about lets say

we have student 
students table

```
student name DOB
ali          03/05/1991
apo          30/05/1993
haz          04/02/1983
nur          03/05/1986
```

how can i group them by DOB but in decades so result should be

```
1980-1989
haz
nur
1990-1999
Ali
Apo
```

thanks

Comment: What data type is the DOB column?

Comment: If you're formatting is infact the way you want it, do it in the reporting system not SQL.  each decade would represent a different header and body section on a report.

Comment: Which RDBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, etc) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DOB column is a `date` or `datetime`, you could simply re-use the first three digits in the year part of the DOB, adding a `0` or `9` to create the decade "grouping":

```
SELECT
    [student name],
    LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR([DOB])), 3) + '0-' +
    LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR([DOB])), 3) + '9' AS Decade
FROM
    Students
```

You can't really `GROUP` anything here, since every student is unique. Your UI should be responsible for presenting students by `[Decade]`.